# Update SQL field for table1 row with lowest id of results found in table2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

Ok so I have two tables:

**table1:**

```
id, featured_id
```

**table2:**

```
id, assigned_to, media_id
```

The query

```
SELECT * FROM table2 where assigned_to = 1
```

would likely yield multiple rows being returned.

I want to then take a query such as the following:

```
UPDATE table1 (featured_id) (WITH LOWEST media_id FROM table2 WHERE table2.assigned_to = table1.id)
```

I guess for matching the table2.assigned_to = table1.id I could use `INNER JOIN`. 
But how to populate with lowest value I have no idea perhaps using order by and limit but not sure on syntax.

Any ideas?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved. (You have already got one product specific answer - perhaps for a dbms not used by use - unfair waste of SO members' time.)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one option joining a subquery with `min`:

```
update table1 t1
   join (select assigned_to, min(media_id) min_media_id
         from table2
         group by assigned_to) t2 on t1.id = t2.assigned_to
set t1.featured_id = min_media_id;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/643c2/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can also write like this.

```
update table1 t1
set t1.featured_id = (select min(media_id) from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.assigned_to)
```